# Characters of group scheme represented by Cartier dual

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes

For a commutative group scheme $\pi \colon G \to S$ finite locally free over a base scheme $S$ we let $A := \pi_* \mathcal{O}_G$ and $A^* = \mathcal{Hom}_\mathcal{O_S}(A, \mathcal{O}_S)$. Then $A^*$ ist again a finite locally free $\mathcal{O}_S$-Algebra and the Cartier dual to $G$ is $G^* := Spec(A^*)$.

I want to understand the fact, that $G^*$ represents the inner hom $T \mapsto Hom_{Grp/T}(G_T, \mathbb{G}_{m,T})$ in the category of $S$-schemes. I already have bijections
$$
Hom_S(S, G^*) \cong \{ x \in \Gamma(S, A)^\times \mid \Delta(x) = x \otimes x, \epsilon(x) = 1\} \cong Hom_{Grp/S}(G, \mathbb{G}_{m,S})
$$

where $\Delta$ and $\epsilon$ denote co-multiplication and augmentation of $A$ respectively. I got two questions:

1. I think that $(G^*)_T \cong (G_T)^*$ canonically, but I am not quite sure why this is true. It would however suffice to obtain $Hom_S(T, G^*) \cong Hom_{Grp/T}(G_T, \mathbb{G}_{m,T})$ for any $S$-scheme $T$.
2. I have absolutely no idea how to show this bijection to be functorial. I have tried to simply chase elements in the significant diagrams, but with all the isomorphisms I have used to obtain the bijection, it just seems impenetrable to me. Is there a way to reduce to a situation where the functoriality is easier to see?

Answer (score 3):

For 1. I think you can proceed as follows. You want to understand $(G^\ast)_T$, but this is just $\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}(f^\ast A^\ast)$ where $f:T\to S$. But,

$$f^\ast A^\ast=\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_T}(f^\ast A,\mathcal{O}_T)$$

and

$$f^\ast A=f^\ast\pi_\ast\mathcal{O}_G=(\pi_T)_\ast(\mathrm{pr}_G^\ast(\mathcal{O}_G))=(\pi_T)_\ast(\mathcal{O}_{G_T})$$

(note I used the fact that $\pi$ was locally free here, in particular, I'm using a baby case of Grauert's theorem). Thus,

$$f^\ast A^\ast=\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_T}(f^\ast A,\mathcal{O}T)=\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_T}((\pi_T)_\ast(\mathcal{O}_{G_T}),\mathcal{O}_T)$$

and so clearly

$$(G^\ast)_T=\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}(f^\ast A^\ast)=\underline{\mathrm{Spec}}(\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_T}((\pi_T)_\ast\mathcal{O}_{G_T},\mathcal{O}_T))=(G_T)^\ast$$

For 2., you can reduce to the case when $S$ is affine, and then I think your question is answered [here](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/624_08/cartier_duality.pdf). Please let me know if I am mistaken!

Comment: Is it immediately clear that $f^*(\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(A, \mathcal{O}_S) = \mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_T}(f^*A, \mathcal{O}_T)$? Also I do not quite see, how I can reduce to the affine case. Indeed then the functoriality would be easy to show. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @sf1 Reduce to affine, and then yes, I think it should be clear :) Let me know if you still have difficulties. For the second condition, reduce to affine using the sheaf condition. Form an open cover by affines, and then use the embedding of your sheaf into the product of the sheaves restricted to these opens, etc.

Comment: I worked on your hints yesterday and this morning, but I'm still stuck. Concerning 1: In order to reduce $f^*(\mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(A, \mathcal{O}_S)) = \mathcal{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_T}(f^*A, \mathcal{O}_T)$ to the affine case, I would need the sheaf Hom to be quasi coherent, but for this I would need $A$ of finite presentation. Furthermore, I would have to define a canonical morphism globally first before checking it is an Iso on affines, or am I mistaken?